Avoid adding strings together when aggregating grouped data using pandas
Strings are added together when using pd.groupby(['col_1','col_2']).sum().For example, for a certain category variable col_3, the possible values are A, B, C, which may become AACBB when grouped for aggregation.
That's something to avoid.
What parameters should I change or what should I do about it?

Well, what would you expect instead? As of now your question is too vague. Please provide a [mre], and that would include an expected output.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do the sample data and results below match your needs?
Create some test data:
    col_1  col_2 col_3  col_4
0      10     10     B      3
1      25     20     C      4
2      15     20     A      3
...

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': np.random.choice([10, 15, 20, 25], size=50),
    'col_2': np.random.choice([10, 20], size=50),
    'col_3': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=50),
    'col_4': np.random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4], size=50)
})

To avoid aggregating over column 3, you can use
df.drop(columns='col_3').groupby(['col_1', 'col_2']).sum()

               col_4
col_1 col_2       
10    10        18
      20        12
15    10        17
      20        10
20    10         8
      20        11
25    10        23
      20        24

The original groupby, which I think replicates your problem:
df.groupby(['col_1', 'col_2']).sum()

                col_3        col_4
col_1 col_2                    
10    10        BBBAAACB     18
      20            AACB     12
15    10          ABABCC     17
      20          AABCCB     10
20    10             CBC      8
      20           BBBCA     11
25    10         AACBCCB     23
      20     CCAAAAACCCC     24


I'm curious, why opt for posting image when text is possible? Please do not upload images of code/data/errors

It's mainly for the multi-index dataframes - they don't display well as text in my view. The code is all text. I've now amended my post to make the first table text as well (the other 2 tables are multi-index).

copy-pasting the output of print(df) works fine in case of multiindex as well (At least Jupyter, Jupyterlab)

Yeah that works nicely, thanks for the tip. I'll update it.

no problem, between 2 fanatic unsung heroes

This may have something to do with the version of pandas, and it's hard to say whether non-numeric type variables should be taken into account when aggregating. So I had to use the command  groupby(['col_1','col_2','col_3']).sum() to fix it.
